# Designing a credit card using abstract date types

Tags: java

So I'm supposed to design and implement an ADT that represents a credit card. It should include  customer name, account number, due date, reward points, and account balance. There should be operations for a credit card charge, a cash advance, a payment, the addition of interest to the balance, and the display of the statistics of the bank account. However when I run my program,
I keep getting an error saying "Class "creditCard" does not have a main method."

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
 import java.io.IOException;
 public class creditCard {

private int customerName;
private int accountNumber;
private int dueDate;
private int rewardPoints;
private int accountBalance;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

double creditLimit = 500;
int user = 0;

public int getCustomerName() {
    return customerName;
}

public void setCustomerName(int customerName) {
    this.customerName = customerName;
}

public int getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public int getDueDate() {
    return dueDate;
}

public void setDueDate(int dueDate) {
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
}

public int getRewardPoints() {
    return rewardPoints;
}

public void setRewardPoints(int rewardPoints) {
    this.rewardPoints = rewardPoints;
}

public int getAccountBalance() {
    return accountBalance;
}

public void setAccountBalance(int accountBalance) {
    this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
}

public String charge(float amount) {
    if (amount > creditLimit) {
        System.out.println("You have exceeded your credit card limit and no charge can be made");
    }
    if (creditLimit - amount > 0) {
        System.out.println("You have exceeded your credit card limit and no charge can be made");
    }
    creditLimit = creditLimit - amount;
    System.out.println("A charge of" + amount + "has been made.");
    String charge = "A charge of" + amount + "has been made.";
    return charge;
}

public String advance(float amount) {
    if (amount > creditLimit) {
        System.out.println("You have exceeded your credit card limit and no charge can be made");
    }
    if (creditLimit - amount > 0) {
        System.out.println("You have exceeded your credit card limit and no charge can be made");
    }
    creditLimit = creditLimit - amount;
    System.out.println("You have withdrawn $ " + amount);
    String advance = "You have withdrawn $ " + amount;
    return advance;
}

public String payment(float amount) {
    creditLimit = creditLimit + amount;
    System.out.println("You have a credit limit of $ " + creditLimit);
    String payment = "You have a credit limit of $ " + creditLimit;
    return payment;
}

public String interest() {
    creditLimit = (creditLimit * 0.02) + creditLimit;
    String interest = "An interest of" + creditLimit * 0.02 + "has been added to your balance";
    return interest;
}

public void statistics(String charge, String advance, String payment, String interest) {

    System.out.println(charge);
    System.out.println(advance);
    System.out.println(payment);
    System.out.println(interest);

}

public void showMenu() {
    while (user!= 5) {
        System.out.println("Choose Charge(1) \nAdvance(2) \nPayment(3) \nInterest(4) \ncStatistics(5)");
    user = input.nextInt();
    switch (user) {
        case 1:
            float amount;
            System.out.println("Enter the amount: ");
            amount = input.nextFloat();
            String charge = charge(amount);
            break;
        case 2:
            float withdrawalAmount;
            System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw: ");
            withdrawalAmount = input.nextFloat();
            String advance = advance(withdrawalAmount);
            break;
        case 3:
            float paymentAmount;
            System.out.println("Enter payment.");
            paymentAmount = input.nextFloat();
            String payment = payment(paymentAmount);
            break;
        case 4:
            String interest = interest();
            break;
        //case 5:
        //statistics(charge, advance, payment, interest);
        //break;
    }
    }
}


public void main(String[] args) {
    showMenu();
}
```

}

Comment: I am pretty sure even if you fix your error, you still failed to comprehend what the task actually asked you to do.

Answer (score 0):

make the main method static.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    showMenu();
}
```

or better create another *entry point class* and put your main there.

```
public class Runner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      CreditCard creditCard= new CreditCard();
      creditCard.showMenu();
      // Do something else

   }
```

Comment: But now I get an error saying "non-static method showMenu() cannot be referenced from a static context."

Comment: @Shiiiro That's why need create another class to run the application.